# How to align the fo:leader vertically in order to have it on the one line with the text

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have a problem with vertical alignment of the leader object and I hope somebody can help me.

I have a block with some text and the rule leader ends the line.

```
<fo:block>
  <fo:inline>
    <pfi:external-graphic imageName="{$onCheckBoxImage}" height="10pt" width="10pt"/>
  </fo:inline>
  <fo:inline vertical-align="sub">
    <xsl:text>Other (please indicate)</xsl:text>
    <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" rule-thickness="0.05mm"/>
  </fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

pfi:external-graphic just adds a small checkbox image.

So the problem is that the **vertical-align="sub"** aligns only the text, and the leader is still aligned to baseline. The goal is to have it like this:

Other (please indicate):_________________________

I have tried to google it but there is not so mach info about this topic. Maybe somebody has some ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You've been shifting the text as well as the leader, so they're both feeling a bit down.  Try:

```
<fo:block>Other (please indicate)<fo:leader vertical-align="sub"
  leader-pattern="rule" rule-thickness="0.05mm" leader-length="50mm" />
</fo:block>
```

To see the effect of what you've been doing, try:

```
<fo:block>
  <fo:inline vertical-align="sub">Other (please indicate)<fo:leader
             leader-pattern="rule" rule-thickness="0.05mm" />
  </fo:inline><fo:leader
       leader-pattern="rule" rule-thickness="0.05mm" />
</fo:block>
```